# White spots on the dough while it was rising

Tags: baking, dough

Yesterday I was trying to make Croissant. I started by making the dough that contained yeast as the rising agent, and after mixing all of the ingredients I left it to rise at room temperature.

After 2 hours when I checked it out I found that there were white spots on the dough, and they are similar to the spots forming on breads when they go bad.

It was very similar to this image except that the small spots in the image are flour but in my dough it were, I guess, fungal things.  [image]

I didn’t know what exactly it was or whether to continue the rising process or not, but I decided to wrap it and put it in the freezer until I know what to do.

By the way, I discovered that I forgot to add sugar (which was in the recipe) to the dough before allowing it to rise), and still I didn’t add it, could this be a factor?

Do you have any idea what are those white spots and are they harmful? And what should I do with the dough in my freezer?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Those white spots are simply flour on the outside of the dough, it would take far longer for mold to develop. It's fine, continue your bake as normal. Leaving sugar out won't hurt anything except the dough will be less sweet.

Comment: Can I add the sugar after taking it out of the freezer and let it rise again? How would that be different from if I had put it in the beginning?

Comment: You aren't going to be able to knead the sugar in and distribute it without messing up the structure of the dough. You could sprinkle it on after you roll it out. That may end up just being a crunchy sugar layer though.